# ¿Cómo encriptar y desencriptar archivos de video en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

¿Cómo puedo hacer para encriptar y desencriptar archivos de video en C#?
Desarrollo una Aplicacion que estara alojada en un CD y mostrara videos que estan alojados en una carpeta dentro de dicho CD , la idea es q estos videos solo puedan ser reproducidos desde la aplicacion

Comment: ¿Los quieres encriptar para que no los copien ? ¿o te refieres a usar un codec de video dentro de tu aplicación?

Answer (score 2):

hola resolvi de esta manera ...funciones de encriptar y desencriptar ...cualquier tipo de archivo..

```
  public MemoryStream Desencriptar(string pFile)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                byte[] ArchivoADesencriptar = File.ReadAllBytes(pFile);
                //string ArchivoADesencriptar = File.ReadAllText(pFile);
                var DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                DES.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Valor.Key());
                DES.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Valor.Key());
                DES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                DES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, DES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cryptoStream.Write(ArchivoADesencriptar, 0, ArchivoADesencriptar.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                File.WriteAllBytes(pFile, memStream.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
            return memStream;
        }

        public MemoryStream Encriptar(string pFile)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                byte[] ArchivoADesencriptar = File.ReadAllBytes(pFile);
                //string ArchivoADesencriptar = File.ReadAllText(pFile);
                var DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                DES.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Valor.Key());
                DES.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Valor.Key());
                DES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                DES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, DES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cryptoStream.Write(ArchivoADesencriptar, 0, ArchivoADesencriptar.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                File.WriteAllBytes(pFile, memStream.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            return memStream;
        }
```